# Grails plugin filterPane associatedProperties doesn't work for java.net.URL

Tags: url, grails, filter, pane

I want to have a filter on the class below ("Debate"). By default I get a filter containing title, published and url. That is fine but when I try filter on the URL I get the following exception. "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.net.URL", see bottom for a full stack trace.

To get around this I added an associatedProperties of url.authority, see below. I figure, since filterpane is comparing to a string I'll give it a string (url.authority).

The problem is the associatedProperties of url.authority never appears on the filter.

I looked through the filterpane code and I can see the following code

```
// Extract out the associations.  These are handled separately from simple properties.
List associatedProps = persistentProps.findAll {
    it.association == true && !it.type.isEnum()
}
```

This is excluding url.authority because url.authority is not a separate domain. I could put url into a domain and I'm guessing it would work but I'd rather not do that as it is altering my underlying code to cater for a plugin and this is very bad practice.

```
class Debate
{
  String title;
  Date published;
  URL url;

  static constraints =
  {
    url nullable : false, unique : true
  }
}
```

By the way, I tried without the excludeProperties and it makes no difference.

```
<filterpane:filterPane dialog="true" domain="com.content.OpenDebate"
associatedProperties="url.port" excludeProperties="url"/>
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.net.URL. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.net.URL
at           grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1587)
at     org.grails.plugin.filterpane.FilterPaneService$_doFilter_closure4.doCall(FilterPaneService.groovy:153)
at     org.grails.plugin.filterpane.FilterPaneService.doFilter(FilterPaneService.groovy:156)
at     org.grails.plugin.filterpane.FilterPaneService.filter(FilterPaneService.groovy:12)
at     com.keane.reg.opendebate.OpenDebateController$_closure1.doCall(OpenDebateController.groovy:29)
at     grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

BTW: Why in the world am I restriced in the tags I can use to describe this post. I have to have a reputation of 1500 or higher to include the words filterpane and associatedproperties. This makes my post less likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

So I've spent enough time on this. I have a workaround.

I added an extra field to my domain class. This provides the url.authority I wanted to filter on.

I have excluded the url from the filter and added author.

see the code below.

```
class Debate
{
  String title;
  Date published;
  URL url;

  // author derived from url
  String getAuthor()
  {
    return(url.authority)
  }

  void setAuthor(String s)
  {
    // do nothing, just a dummy.
  }

  static constraints =
  {
    url nullable : false, unique : true
  }

  @Override
  String toString()
  {
    return "${url} : ${title} : ${author} : ${published}";
  }



<filterpane:filterPane dialog="true" domain="com.content.OpenDebate" 
filterProperties="${['author', 'title', 'published']}"
filterPropertyValues="${[published:[precision:'day']]}"/>
```